# Unlocking bootloader for samsung A10 only

Tags: bootloader, superuser

Is there any possible way to unlock bootloader on samsung A10..I've tried fastboot I've tried everything..LXDE?..I'm dying here..

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#unlocking-bootloader

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-unsamlock-bootloader-unlock-for-samsung-us-canada-devices.4215101